# I am working on a project of detecting Phising Urls. But I am getting an error whenever I am trying to extract features and store them in list

Tags: url, extract

I am working on a project of detecting Phising Urls using Machine Learning. But I am getting an error whenever I am trying to extract features and store them in list. the code is
#Extracting the feautres & storing them in a list

I am getting this error gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
1347             try:
-> 1348                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
1349                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

16 frames
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
1349                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
1350             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1351                 raise URLError(err)
1352             r = h.getresponse()
1353         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdfEQ.png)
Is it because of I am using Alexa dataset in estimating web trafficing.

I am trying to extract features from the urls and convert them into a dataframe where the columns will be 'Domain', 'Have_IP', 'Have_At', 'URL_Length', 'URL_Depth','Redirection','https_Domain', 'TinyURL', 'Prefix/Suffix', 'DNS_Record', 'Web_Traffic', 'Domain_Age', 'Domain_End', 'iFrame', 'Mouse_Over','Right_Click', 'Web_Forwards', 'Label'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyDps.png)